# delMax() api - Priority Queue

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

In the [lecture](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1) from Sedgewick,

below is the java code, for deleting max element from heap,

### [image]

Question:

If I consider line, `exch(1, N--)`, why to decrement `N` after swapping? Again he access right index with `+1` to loiter in `pq[N+1] = null` for loitering. I see code as,

```
public Key delMax(){
  Key max = pq[1];
  exch(1, N);
  sink(1);
  pq[N] = null;
  return max;
}
```

Comment: It would help to edit the question to give full context, including the definition of `exch()` and `sink()` and declaration of `N`.

Comment: ^ none of that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough context to know, but my guess would be that `N` is an instance variable (field) of the class that is also used by `sink()`, so your rewrite might not be equivalent.

You can always try it and see: you can test his version and your version and see if they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be obvious that, if you delete something, you now have fewer things. With your changes, N stays the same.

Comment: It's sad that anonymous ignorant fools downvote good answers that they don't understand.